# Binding data to div element and highlight the selected using Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I want to display the data in a div element and highlight the default one as selected when the page is loaded, and when I click the other item which is not selected, the selected item should change the value for this .$scope.selectedItem property.

for e.g. I have this data

```
Item 1
Item 2

//this is the item list
 this.$scope.items = items;

//this is the selected item
this.$scope.selectedItem = selectedItem;

//html. I don't know how to design this, since I don't know how to bind the data to div element.

<div></div>
```

if I have a div element, how can I bind the data and display it. And from there, how I can save the selected value when I select an item?

Sorry I am new to Angular.js So I'm confused at the moment.

Comment: Can you also show your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You could have ng-click on the div itself.. something like this:

```
 <div ng-click="clicked('one')">
   Item One
  </div>

  <div ng-click="clicked('two')">
   Item Two
  </div>
```

In controller:

```
 $scope.clicked = function(item) {
      $scope.selectedItem = item;
    };
```

you can use `ng-class` to decorate the div to have hilight..

Comment: Hi @AbdelRaoof- If my items come from here this.$scope.items, how can I bind the data to div element?

Comment: may be you can post how your view and controller look like? Without that I can give you only generic answer like above...